# Mat Table Angular only last data is getting printed from array that too each letter in each row

Tags: angular, mat-table

table.component.ts

```
displayColumns: string[] = [ 'Feedback'] ;
listData: MatTableDataSource<any> ;
//listData;
myJSON ;
records: number;
objPutss: Post;
catupdated = false;
searchKey: string ;
@ViewChild(MatSort , {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator , {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator ;

tableLoad(event: any) {
this.fdbif = false;
  const selcetdCategoryCount = event.target.innerHTML;
this._responseService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.toolDataSet = data;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < this.toolDataSet.length ; i++) {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
  if (this.toolDataSet[i].Tool == this.selectedTool) {
      if(this.toolDataSet[i].Corrected_Category == selcetdCategoryCount){
      this.fdb[i]=this.toolDataSet[i].Feedback;
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.fdb[i]) ;
            this.listData.sort = this.sort;
  this.listData.paginator = this.paginator ;
      this.countt++;
      }
  }
  }

  console.log(this.countt);
              console.log(this.fdb);
         // this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.fdb) ;
   });
  }
```

table.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="countClicked">
        <mat-table [dataSource]= "listData" matSort >      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Feedback">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header ><span>Feedback </span></mat-header- 
      cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "  >
                {{element}}
            </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>

     <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row> 
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator showFirstLastButtons
[pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

I'm able to get the data in console log i.e if there are five rows of data those five rows i'm able to see in cosole log where as in the mat-table only the 5th(last) row gets displayed that too each letter of a word is displayed in each row
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE1Pe.png)

console.log(countt) gives me exact count

Can somebody please help me in solving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rajesh I could see that you are iterating through the loop and creating new dataSource   `this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.fdb[i]) ;`...Mat table works in such a way that you just have to pass the entire array to the table object and it will take care of parsing and constructing the value.

My recommandation, dont create the MatTableDataSource inside for loop, create the data in array format that you would wish to print on that table and just pass the array to mat table.

Demo link: [Array to mat table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-nz1bfx)